# is_valid() vs clean() django forms

Tags: django, forms, validation

In the process of finding a way to validate my django forms, I came across two methods is_valid() and clean() in the django docs. Can anyone enlighten me the how they are different/same? What are the pros and cons of either?

Thanks.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

`is_valid()` calls `clean()` on the form automatically.  You use `is_valid()` in your views, and `clean()` in your form classes.

Your `clean()` function will return `self.cleaned_data` which if you will notice in the following view is not handled by you as the programmer.

```
form = myforms.SettingsForm(request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
   name = form.cleaned_data['name']
   #do stuff
```

You didn't have to do `clean_data = form.is_valid()` because `is_valid()` will call clean and overwrite data in the form object to be cleaned.  So everything in your `if form.is_valid()` block will be clean and valid.  The `name` field in your block will be the sanitized version which is not necessarily what was in `request.POST`.

**Update**
You can also display error messages with this.  In `clean()` if the form data isn't valid you can set an error message on a field like this:

```
self._errors['email'] = [u'Email is already in use']
```

Now `is_valid()` will return False, so in the else block you can redisplay the page with your overwritten form object and it will display the error message if your template uses the error string.

Comment: hi..what would happen if the form does not have a function called clean() when the is_valid() is called in the views.py function?

Comment: I am a bit confused on when the clean_fieldName function in the form class is called

Comment: In more recent versions of Django, `clean()` will not necessarily return `self.cleaned_data`.  Sometimes, especially for formsets, it doesn't return anything.  This gave me trouble before.  They lifted this requirement several versions ago.

Answer (score 6):

Just wanted to add that the best way now to add an error to a form you're manually validating in is_valid() is to use `Form.add_error(field, error)` to conform with Django's ErrorDict object.

Doing

```
self._errors['field'] = ['error message']
```

will come out funky when rendering `{{form.errors}}`, like:

```
fielderror messsage
```

instead of the expected

```
field
    -error message
```

so instead do:

```
self.add_error('email', 'Email is already in use')
```

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.add_error