# UpdateView causing error "__init__() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)"

Tags: python, django

I tried so many cases to fix this error "the **init**() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)" but have not been able to resolve it.

Note: I am using Django's default auth user model, and the DB is MySQL.

**`URLS.PY`**

```
url(r'^change-password$', ChangePasswordView.as_view()),
```

**FORMS.PY**

```
class PasswordChangForm(forms.Form):
    new_password1 = forms.CharField(max_length=20,required=True)
    new_password2 = forms.CharField(max_length=20,required=True)


    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = user
        super(PasswordChangForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def clean(self):
        try:
            print self.cleaned_data.get('new_password1')
            print self.cleaned_data.get('new_password2')
            password1 = self.cleaned_data.get('new_password1')
            password2 = self.cleaned_data['new_password2']
            if password1 and password2:
                if password1 != password2:
                    raise forms.ValidationError('password_mismatch')
                else:
                    try:
                        print "tryyy.."
                        print self.user
                        user = User.objects.get(username=self.user)
                        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data.get('new_password1'))
                        user.save()
                        return user
                    except User.DoesNotExist:
                        return forms.ValidationError('Oops Some thing went Wrong..')
        except KeyError:
            raise forms.ValidationError('The password field was blank.')
```

**`VIEWS.PY`**

```
class ChangePasswordView(UpdateView):
    template_name = 'people/change_password.html'
    form_class = PasswordChangForm
    model = User

#When I use get_form, it prevents __init__ error. But in the forms.py "clean" method is never calling. This results no validation and not saving data in the DB
'''def get_form(self, form_class):
    print "iam in getform..."
    return form_class(self.request.user)'''

def get_object(self):
    return User.objects.get(username=self.request.user)


'''def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return super(YourView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)'''

def get_success_url(self):
    print "get_success_url"
    print self.request.user
    return '/welcome'

def form_valid(self, form):
    print "valid"
    #instance = form.save(commit=False)
    #instance.user = self.request.user
    return super(ChangePasswordView, self).form_valid(form)

def form_invalid(self,form):
    print "form_invalid"
    print form.errors
    return super(ChangePasswordView, self).form_invalid(form)
```

Could anyone help me understand what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Where is the complete stack trace?

Comment: @mu sorry..didnt get...could you explain clearly

Comment: @mu無 __init__() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)

Comment: @mu無 BTW, When  I return get_form method return form_class(user = self.request.user), then it prevents __init__() error. But in the forms.py "clean" method is never calling in PasswordChangForm Class. This results no validation and not saving data in the DB

Comment: It seems very strange that db is affected inside form @clean@ method.

Comment: @KlassIvan Please advice..what I have to do..spent atleast 1 day for this silly bug

Comment: @vamsi, you should do db changes somewhere in your django view (actually controller), not in you form and definitely not in from method called `clean` - it's totally implicit and not obvious design. Also you don't need to pass user model to form instance in that case. So I would vote up for custom `post` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is here: (in `get_form` method)

```
def get_form(self, form_class):
    return form_class(self.request.user)
```

It should be

```
def get_form(self, form_class):
    return form_class(user=self.request.user)
```

Also override the post method(from comments section):

```
class ChangePasswordView(UpdateView):
     ....
     def post(self, request,  *args, **kwargs):
           form= self.form_class(request.POST)
           if form.is_valid():
               #do something
           else:
               #raise error
           return super(ChangePasswordView, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I tried this case also..It prevents __init__ error. But in the forms.py "clean" method is never calling in PasswordChangForm Class. This results no validation and not saving data in the DB

Comment: that means, form's is_valid() method hasn't been called. You can call is_valid method by overriding the post method of UpdateView

Comment: Your case is the last option for me to resolve.. Any other option ?

Comment: Is your form getting validated ?

Comment: according to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5083587/2696165 you need to call is_valid method for calling clean method, So to my opinion, overriding `post` is the best option.

Comment: No need to override is_valid() in forms.py. You need to override view's post method to call is_valid(), check my answer

Comment: is it possible to discuss at skype for just 5min..if you dont mine ?

Comment: sorry, can't do. But feel free to mail me ruddra90@gmail.com

Comment: no probs..The problem is custom post method or some other method what I did earlier never takes to clean method

Comment: UpdateView has its own post method, so overriding it should work. I dunno what you meant by custom post method and how have you placed post method. And by the way, the way you are accessing `user` in `clean` method shouldn't work. Because clean's `user` and __init__'s `user` are in different scopes. and clean method is appropriate for validation purpose. You should do that in views.py(just a suggestion).

Comment: sent an email ..please check it out and let me know..I am almost in the end