# Django. Best way to have unique email in User model?

Tags: python, django, email

I have a UserProfile model to add some things to my User model and one thing I want to do is have unique email for users so I added an email attribute to my UserProfile model and set it to `unique=True` like this :

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name="profile")
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    avatar = models.ForeignKey(Avatar)
    ...
```

I created a custom form for the registration to add some infos directly to my UserProfile :

```
class CreateUserForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=30, label="Pseudo")
    password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput, label="Password")
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput, label="Confirmez pwd")
    email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.EmailInput, label="E-mail")
    avatar = AvatarChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect, queryset=Avatar.objects.all(), label="Avatar")

    def clean_username(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data.get('username')

        if User.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError("This username is already used")

        return username

    def clean_password2(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get('password1')
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get('password2')

        if password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Your passwords do not match")

        return password1

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')

        if UserProfile.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError("This email is already used")

        return email
```

And then in my views.py I treat my form like that :

```
def create_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreateUserForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.clean_username()
            email = form.clean_email()
            password = form.clean_password2()
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            avatar = form.cleaned_data['avatar']

            user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, password=password)
            user.save()

            user_profile = UserProfile(user=user, email=email, avatar=avatar)
            user_profile.save()

    else:
        form = CreateUserForm()

    return render(request, 'accounts/create.html', locals())
```

Finally I used the email of the form for my UserProfile model and not for my User model. And by this way I have a unique email for my users. And it's working.

Am I doing it right or is there a better way to achieve what I want ?

Comment: Are you using Django's built in User model?  Seems like you should be based on your UserProfile class fields.  If so, I'm not sure you have to rewrite all of this and instead should just subclass AbstractUser

Comment: I prefer using the OneToOneField method with UserProfile linked to User, because I don't want to rewrite the authentification process

Comment: You actually don't have to rewrite anything, authentication process will be kept; you can see that Django's User model is just a [simple subclass of AbstractUser](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L366).  This is how pydanny does it as well in [cookiecutter](https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django/blob/master/%7B%7Bcookiecutter.repo_name%7D%7D/%7B%7Bcookiecutter.repo_name%7D%7D/users/models.py#L12).  I might be misunderstanding what you're trying to do though.

Comment: Yeah I just red the link you gave me. And User model is just an extension of AbstractUser. I did the OneToOneField method because it is suggested like that in the doc (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model). But I'll test what you propose. Thanks !

Comment: Interesting to know how you implemented the reset password functionality? It uses the email from User object but you dont have an email for the User model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track, the only thing that doesn't look right is that you shouldn't call `clean` method manually like this:

```
# These are not needed in your view method
username = form.clean_username()
email = form.clean_email()
password = form.clean_password2()
```

They are already called by `form.is_valid()`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5083493/is-valid-vs-clean-django-forms) SO question for details.

Comment: ok great, I didn't know that form.is_valid() called the clean methods. Thanks !