# DJANGO FORMS VALIDATION

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-templates

There are different ways of validation in Django forms like clean(), is_valid() and validators. I want to know When to use which method and the difference among them ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [is\_valid() vs clean() django forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5083493/is-valid-vs-clean-django-forms)

Answer (score 0):

`is_valid()` calls `clean()` on the form automatically. You use `is_valid()` in your views.py file, and `clean()` in your forms.

They both achieve the same result, but are used in different cases.

Answer (score 0):

use is_valid() when you want to be sure the form contains valid inputs

use clean() to clean inputs. Not that the inputs are not valid but maybe there are cleaning you want to do to enforce consistency in your database.